# Populate a class and then use it later

Tags: vb.net, class, variables

I have a class like

```
Public Class Location
    Public Name As String
    Public Column As Integer
    Public Row As Integer
    Public Occupant As String
End Class
```

In my code I have a subroutine to fill the class

```
Sub Populate Location(ByValue coordinate As String)
    Dim Here As New Location
    Here.Location = coordinate.SubString(0,3)
    Here.Column = SomeFunction(coordinate, Gere.location)
    Here.Row = AnotherFunction(coordinate, Here.Column)
    Here.Occupant = ArrayOfOccupant(column, row)
End Sub
```

All of that is filled in one press of a button.
Later I want to click another button and use the Here class to do other things.

What are my options or what do I search for?

Comment: Your Sub does not even compile as written.  Please only post code that compiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is, your class object only exists inside that procedure.

```vb
Dim Here As New Location    ' variable declaration, instancing
                            ' Scope is this module or form

Sub PopulateLocation(ByValue coordinate As String)
    ' assuming this might get reused, create a new instance
    Here = New Location            

    Here.Location = coordinate.SubString(0,3)
    Here.Column = SomeFunction(coordinate, Here.location)
    Here.Row = AnotherFunction(coordinate, Here.Column)
    Here.Occupant = ArrayOfOccupant(column, row)
End Sub
```

Other subs in that module will have access to `Here` because it now has class/module level `Scope`

Comment: That method cannot compile correctly as there is a space in the name of the method.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway good point, I obviously just copied his code block as a starting point.  Fixed.